# Laravel dynamic rule for unique value

Tags: validation, laravel, unique

At the moment I'm using Laravel for one of my projects. For a given object (User Group) I've got a Controller, Model and CreateUserGroupRequest set up. The Request object has one simple rule:

```
public function rules()
{
    return [
        'name' => 'required|unique:user_groups|min:3'
    ];
}
```

When I'm trying to update any given user group it fails when I don't change the name. Obviously this is because the name itself is already in use, by itself. How am I supposed to set the "ignore_id" dynamically? Or should I use `$this->validtor($request, ['name' => 'required|unique:user_groups:' . $usergroup->id . '|min:3'])` in all update methods?

Comment: Can you just remove "required", so your data doesn't need to have name set, but if it does, then the following rules apply?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the help of mark's answer ([Laravel 5 Validation unique pass variable placeholder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29696772/laravel-5-validation-unique-pass-variable-placeholder)) I found a solution. In my CreateUserGroupRequest (which has been renamed to UserGroupRequest since it's now used for creating and editing) I'm referencing the $id (my identifying variable from the PATCH route, /usergroup/1 and where $id = 1) which is also in the request. I wasn't aware that was even possible there.

```
public function rules()
{
    return [
        'name' => 'required|unique:user_groups,name,' . $this->segment(2) . ':|min:3'
    ];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need this part from laravel documentation : 
Forcing A Unique Rule To Ignore A Given ID:

Sometimes, you may wish to ignore a given ID during the unique check. For example, consider an "update profile" screen that includes the user's name, e-mail address, and location. Of course, you will want to verify that the e-mail address is unique. However, if the user only changes the name field and not the e-mail field, you do not want a validation error to be thrown because the user is already the owner of the e-mail address. You only want to throw a validation error if the user provides an e-mail address that is already used by a different user. To tell the unique rule to ignore the user's ID, you may pass the ID as the third parameter:

```
'email' => 'unique:users,email_address,'.$user->id
```

source : http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/validation#rule-unique

Comment: Thanks for your reply but I think I can only use that (as I mentioned) in the method itself, and not when I'm trying to reuse my CreateUserGroupRequest class. Or is there some magical way to throw a user group (or any database fetched row) to the Request object?

Comment: i can not understand what you mean, if you have data inCreateUserGroupRequest and you have eloquent model of your table, why you can not connect this dates each other

Comment: Because the code resides in another file and the Request is first validated and if it fails at any time the code within my controller's update method is never executed. Therefore I thought I had to pass the user group object somehow to the custom Request class. But I found an intro to the answer and posted it as well. Thanks for thinking with me!